# Simple text captcha solving

Tags: imacros

I'm pretty new to imacros but have hit a snag when recording. The website I'm using requires a basic captcha such as 5+3= and they are all like that.

Is it possible to extract that and do that without external plugins or library's?

Sorry for the short question.

I have had a look around and only found actual image captcha examples available, this is text and a textbox.

Comment: Not without some sort of OCR.

Comment: Would this not be possible with the EXTRACTION (http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction) method?

Comment: Use deathbycaptcha.com API.